# Issue while retrieving data from the mySQL database in AIX system

Tags: java, mysql, database, linux, aix

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL database table. To do that, I use following code on various platforms. My code works perfectly on Windows and Linux platforms. But when I use same code in AIX 6.1, it does not retrieve correct data.

The Main Function:

```
String storedstring = objDBUtil.lookup(0);
logger.info(storedstring);
```

The Database Util Function:

```
public String lookup(String number) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT info FROM records WHERE Snumber=?";

    Connection dbConn = connect();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);

    try {
           stmt.setString(1, number);

           ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            try {
                if (!rs.next()) {
                    throw new TException("does not exist in the database");
                }
                return  rs.getString(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Unexpected exception caught during auth: " + e.getClass().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }finally {
                rs.close();
            }
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
    } finally {
        dbConn.close();
    }
}
```

Output of the main function on Windows, I get the entire string from the database. But exact code gives me encrypted value on AIX machine.

> Output on AIX machine [B@62637268

Comment: It's not an encrypted value. It's the return value of the `toString()` method of an object which is an array of `boolean`s, and which the JVM uniquely identifies with the number `62637268` (sort of pointer, but you know, Java has not pointers). For comparison, test the following code: `new Object().toString();`

Comment: Not relevant to the question: Besides, I'm wondering if `number` does really have to be a String rather than an int or BigInteger, which would additionally prevent exploitation by a malformed or malicious parameter.

Comment: @ignis Based on the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29), `[B` means an array of bytes instead of booleans, which is more reasonable as a result of a database query. s

Comment: @billc.cn Yes, you are correct, I'm sorry.

Comment: What is the datatype of the INFO field?
Instead of rs.getString(1) you could try rs.getObject(1) and look at what you're getting back. That should give you some ideas about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Issue was with connector file. I was using older version of connector file.

MySQL version I was using:
mysql-5.5.2-m2-aix5.3-powerpc-64bit

Non working version of Mysql connector with above mysql: 
mysql-connector-java-3.1.7-bin.jar

Working version of MySQL connctor with above mysql:
New version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar

Thank you everyone for looking into my question and trying to help me. Really appreciated.